# Garage door openers - BLDC x AC monophasic - Is that possible?

Tags: ac, power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor, induction-motor, electrical

As far as I know, electronic control boards for garage doors, they basically control two main types of motors:

- AC induction monophasic, one neutral and two phases, driven by TRIAC or relay. It takes long time for close/open garage door.
- BLDC, driven by inverter. With it it is possible to reach much faster opening/closing time of the garage door, around 4 seconds for a complete cycle.

A representative of companies that makes electrical motors told me that there are few companies selling an "additional board" that connects to the control board from any standard garage door already installed (I mean only the one which controls AC induction motors) and also to the motor. He said that using that addon board the AC motors can reach almost the same speed of closing/opening the garage door compared to the BLDC type, a much lower time compared to the original installation (without the addon board).

Could that be really possible? How would be the electronics of such thing?

Regards.

Comment: THat seems unlikely for a constant speed AC motor with a fixed gear ratio.

Comment: "A representative of companies **that makes electrical motors**" - are you sure he didn't mean an adapter board for a more powerful motor?

Answer (score 0):

the board sounds like a variable frequency drive.

Comment: You may be correct. To make the answer useful to the OP and to others who come after can you please add a little more explanation for those not aware of what VFDs are or how they are advantageous in this application.